Is security level of VPN equivalent to WPA3 provided by TP-Link Home router?
need help with determining if my current VPN is on par with WPA3 provided by TP LINK AX1800 which is complimentary gift but doesn’t meet my need of two internet connections. Should I

add a WAN switch such as ER-605 to an existing old router which cannot be replaced due to existing VoIP contract but has older WiFi protocol? And use my existing VPN on its outdated WiFi protocol? This allows me to sell AX1800 to partially recover cost of purchasing WAN switch.
More expensive solution which is keep  AX1800 and purchase WAN switch. Also is WiFi 6  not somewhat excessive when I already have VPN? And my network devices are less than 10 feet away from router?


What is the connection between WiFI 6 and using a VPN? Unless you have WiFi 6 wireless adapters there is little benefit to a router that supports it. If it's free there is no reason to not use it. Clarification to your question can be done be editing it.

There are attacks of Wifi level that can't be prevented by VPN, e.g. deauthentication attacks that will kick you out of the Wifi.

Since from answers I got so far are related to speed and reliability of connection rather than less security, and my banks accept for my NordVpN Mobile with WiFi4, for my use case, I cannot find reason to upgrade to WiFi 6 and drop NordVPN Mobile App ; and continue my NordVPN mobile with WiFi4 for online banking not only for my need to reduce costs of (1) mobile data (live media ongoing), (2) environment concern of dumping old router to improve factors unrelated to security.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
